# High ping latency between two machines

Tags: vpn, ping, latency, tailscale

I am trying to ping a machine over tailscale and seeing very high latency numbers (> 3000 ms). The machines are very closely geo located. One of them is behind a Comcast router, and another is behind AT&T Fiber. How should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

If your traffic is [routing through a DERP as explained in Tailscale's troubleshooting guide](https://tailscale.com/kb/1023/troubleshooting/#how-do-i-know-if-my-traffic-is-being-routed-through-derp), you may need to [open one or more ports](https://tailscale.com/kb/1082/firewall-ports/) in order to connect your machines directly.

Use the [Tailscale CLI](https://tailscale.com/kb/1080/cli) to run the [`tailscale status`](https://tailscale.com/kb/1080/cli/#status) command. If you see output in the form of `relay "code"`, then your traffic is being routed via a [relay server](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-tailscale-works/#encrypted-tcp-relays-derp) that has “code” as its location.

If there is no `relay "code"` line in the `tailscale status` output, then your traffic is not being routed through DERP.

Also, the [`tailscale ping`](https://tailscale.com/kb/1023/troubleshooting/#how-do-i-know-if-my-traffic-is-being-routed-through-derp:%7E:text=Also%2C%20the,or%20via%20DERP.) command will indicate whether a successful ping was by direct path or via DERP.

Example:

```
tailscale ping node2

pong from node2 (100.99.98.96) via DERP(sea) in 242ms
pong from node2 (100.99.98.96) via 1.2.3.4:1234 in 127ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a traceroute to the machine. Tailscale will very often fallback to a cloud relay which can add a lot of latency to the connection even when they are physically close.